Calculate % gain of closed trades, plot a label under Long trade Entry bars / above Short trade entry bars IF the gain is above a threshold
I got if to work (see code below), but it plots a ton of labels above every strategy entry bar where the condition is true, instead of plotting only one label.  Can someone help?
Thanks!
    for tradeNo = 0 to strategy.closedtrades - 1
        ProfitPct_high = 0.0
        ProfitPct_low  = 0.0
        entryP = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(tradeNo)
        exitP = strategy.closedtrades.exit_price(tradeNo)
        profit_this_trade = exitP / entryP - 1
        ProfitPct_high := profit_this_trade > ProfitPct_high ? profit_this_trade : ProfitPct_high
        ProfitPct_low := profit_this_trade > ProfitPct_low ? profit_this_trade : ProfitPct_low
        if profit_this_trade > 0.005 and strategy.closedtrades.size(tradeNo) > 0 //profit_this_trade > (ProfitPct_high * percentile) //
            label.new(strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(tradeNo), low, str.tostring(profit_this_trade*100, "#.##") + "%", color=#5252ffb0, style=label.style_label_up)
        if profit_this_trade > 0.005 and strategy.closedtrades.size(tradeNo) < 0 //profit_this_trade < (ProfitPct_high * percentile) and strategy.closedtrades.size(tradeNo) < 0
            label.new(strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(tradeNo), high, str.tostring(profit_this_trade*100, "#.##") + "%", color=#eb34a5b0, style=label.style_label_down)


What I am expecting is to see one label plotted above or below a candle where the condition is true, but it plots a ton of labels each time. So many that I can't count them.

Here below the correct code. Maybe there's a simpler way, but this works.
    for tradeNo = 0 to strategy.closedtrades - 1
    ProfitPct_high = 0.0
    ProfitPct_low  = 0.0
    entryP = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(tradeNo)
    exitP = strategy.closedtrades.exit_price(tradeNo)
    profit_this_trade_long = exitP / entryP - 1
    profit_this_trade_short = (entryP-exitP)/entryP
    ProfitPct_high := strategy.closedtrades.size(tradeNo) > 0 ? profit_this_trade_long > ProfitPct_high ? profit_this_trade_long : ProfitPct_high : na
    ProfitPct_low := strategy.closedtrades.size(tradeNo) < 0 ? profit_this_trade_short > ProfitPct_low ? profit_this_trade_short : ProfitPct_low : na
    if strategy.closedtrades.size(tradeNo) > 0 and profit_this_trade_long > 0.05 //profit_this_trade_long > (ProfitPct_high * percentile) //
        lbl = label.new(strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(tradeNo), na)
        label.set_text( lbl, str.tostring(profit_this_trade_long*100, "#.##") + "%")
        label.set_color(lbl, #9696fcd7)
        label.set_yloc( lbl, yloc.belowbar)
        label.set_size(lbl, size.tiny)
        label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_up)
    if strategy.closedtrades.size(tradeNo) < 0 and profit_this_trade_short > 0.03 //profit_this_trade_short > (ProfitPct_high * percentile) //
        lbl = label.new(strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(tradeNo), na)
        label.set_text( lbl, str.tostring(profit_this_trade_short*100, "#.##") + "%")
        label.set_color(lbl, #faa1e7d8)
        label.set_yloc( lbl, yloc.abovebar)
        label.set_size(lbl, size.tiny)
        label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_down)


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
